# Does the sub class inherit the private data members too in c++? But are accessed through the public methods of the super class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm new to c++. I used to believe that the super class private data members and member functions are not inherited by the derived class. But recently I saw a program in which the private member of the super class could be accessed through its public member function. How is it possible when the derived class doesn't have the private data member ..? please clear my concept if I am wrong .

Comment: It's possible because the sub class **is-a** super class. That's what inheritance means. It therefore must inherit the private members.

Comment: so you are saying that it inherits the private members too but they are only visible to the public methods of the super class ?

Comment: Precisely. To be a bit more exact: they are only accessible in scopes where the static type of the object is assumed to be of the super class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private data members of a class are not accessible from other classes when they are set as **private**.

But with the use of **return functions**, it is possible for the child classes to retrieve private data members from the parent class.

Example

```
class Parent{
    int age = 35;

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
}

class Child : public Parent{

}

int main(){
    Child c;
    printf("%d", c.getAge());
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
35
```

Answer (score 1):

> used to believe that the super class private data members and member functions are not inherited by the derived class.

Your understanding is a bit flawed.

The private members still exist in the base class. They are simply not directly accessible by the derived class.